# Undefined method 'bookings' for nil:NilClas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using nested routes,I have :booking table and :hotel table
In my routes.rb

```
resources :hotels do
  resources :bookings
end
```

In my hotel show.html. erb

```
<%= link_to 'Book Now', new_booking_path(:hotel_id => @hotel.id) %>
```

In my bookings_controller.rb

```
def new 
  @booking = @hotel.bookings.build 
end
```

When the link is clicked, it generates a link

```
localhost:3000/bookings/new?hotel_id=4
```

But I still get an error

```
NoMethodError

Undefined method 'bookings' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source from

def new 
  @booking = @hotel.bookings.build
end
```

Comment: you are passing `hotel_id`, the wrong way `@hotel..id`. It should be `@hotel.id`

Comment: That's just typographical error... I made the mistake typing this questions on stack exchange Mobile app

Comment: can you show the output of your rake routes ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're not retrieving a Hotel object in your `new` method for your controller. So when you call `bookings` on the @hotel variable, the nil exception is thrown. It should look something like:

**bookings_controller.rb:**

```
def new
  @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
  @booking = @hotel.bookings.build
end
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake to find @hotel here, Please do this -

In bookings_controller.rb -

```
def new
  @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
  if @hotel.present?
    @booking = @hotel.bookings.build
    render :new
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end 
end
```